# How Can i Prevent ValueError in this code?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to check if a string is a number is greater than 1. The string format is Minutes:Seconds = 0:12 but sometimes the format is like 11:12

This the code I'm using now sometimes I get an error 'ValueError: invalid literal for int()' if the format is like 11:12 how can I prevent this from happening?

```
length = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/path[2]").text
# length output would be something like 11:28
x = length.split(":")
if int(x[0]) < 1:
    print("Less than 1 minute.")
else:
    pass
```

how can I prevent this 'ValueError: invalid literal for int()' from happening?

Comment: You could use `try/except` statements to except the ValueError and then `# do something`

Comment: That would not fail for the string `11:12`.  You must be getting alpha characters in there, like `one:two`.  Are you printing the value of `length` every time so you can see what fails?

Comment: Please include the *entire* error message.  The one you cite also tells you what the invalid value is.  You need to first check for whatever the bad string is.
In most cases, it's simply that you have an empty string.  Check for that first.

Answer (score 0):

Try testing for whether x[0] is actually a digit before you try converting the string to an integer.  In your case, since you only want digits < 1, i.e. 0, you can test for whether x[0] is a single digit with isdigit().  Otherwise you could check x[0][0] if you were testing the first character in for 2-digit numbers, etc. There are many other approaches too, for example, you could also just check for whether str(x[0]) == '0' whether it's initially a number or string, though that would include the last example below, which you may not want.

```
text2try = ['11:28', 'hi:there', '9:28', '0:28', '01234']

for length in text2try:
    # if str(length[0]) == '0':   # to check just the first character
    x = length.split(":")
    if x[0].isdigit() and int(x[0]) < 1:
        print(x[0], "Less than 1 minute.")
```